# Adding extra variables to a formula

Tags: r, syntax, formula

I want to add extra variables to a formula, with the use of a separate object `part_B`. As an example:

```
part_A <- as.formula("y ~ x1")
part_B <- c("x2", "x3")
```

I tried a couple of things, but one issue is that you cannot call `as.formula` on the object `part_B` (because in that case I could have created the formula by combining character vectors).

Desired Result

```
as.formula("y ~ x1 + x2 + x3")
```

Is there any way to do this? I guess one solution would be to create a function that writes the character vector as `"y ~ x1 + x2 + x3"` so it can be fed to `as.formula`.

Comment: Shamefully, I know of no better way than `fml <- as.formula(paste("~", part_B[1], "+, part_B[2]))` and then `update(part_A, fml)`. `formula.tools` is inadequate. You might try the `formulaic` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use reformulate and update like this:

```
update(part_A, reformulate(c(".", part_B)))
## y ~ x1 + x2 + x3
```

This also works:

```
v <- all.vars(part_A)
reformulate(c(v[-1], part_B), v[1])
## y ~ x1 + x2 + x3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write `part_A` as a vector instead:

```
part_A <- c("y", "x1")
part_B <- c("x2", "x3")

new_formula <- as.formula(paste(part_A[1], paste(c(part_A[2], part_B), collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ "))
```